# Accessing Class defined inside an Object in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have two files each defining an Object. Both defined in the same package.

- object1 has ClassA
- object2 has the main method.

When I try to reference ClassA in object2, I get an error that ClassA cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong? If the objects are in the same default namespace, shouldn't they be able to see each other?

Comment: Please add some code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
object object2{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val a = new object1.ClassA()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to reference just ClassA or will I always need to precede it with object1?